# About the past tense

Tags: past-tense

I've recently listened to people talking in interviews and from time to time they use "*did* (past tense) + the verb in the *simple present tense*". For example, instead of saying "I saw this person the other day", they say "I did see this person the other day". Please, my question is in what kind of situation is it correct to talk like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's this kind of sentence or style called in the grammar terminology?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190524/whats-this-kind-of-sentence-or-style-called-in-the-grammar-terminology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of "did" is when the speaker is affirming or emphasising that they saw someone, particularly where there might be doubt

> Did you see Joe yesterday?
> Yes I **did** see him.

Without "did" it becomes the answer to a different question.

> Who did you see yesterday?
> I saw Joe.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!